# java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: META_INF/LICENSE.txt

Tags: java, gradle, java-web-start

This is my first time using Java Web Start. This is for a demo version of my application. I have uploaded the JAR to my server, and created a JNLP file. When I run the file locally, I get the exception shown below.

[image]

[This](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/deploymentInDepth/jnlpFileSyntax.html) was the reference I was reading, and below is my JNLP file.

DerbyPro.jnlp

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="" href="">
    <information>
        <title>Derby Pro</title>
        <vendor>Neon Orb</vendor>
        <icon href="http://neonorb.com/images/derby-pro/derby-pro-icon-hd.png"/>
        <offline-allowed/>
    </information>

    <resources>
        <j2se version="1.8+" href=
                "http://neonorb.com"/>
        <jar href="http://neonorb.com/clientportal/derby-pro-demo.jar"
             main="true" />
    </resources>

    <application-desc
            name="Derby Pro"
            main-class="com.neonorb.derbypro.main.DerbyPro"
            width="300"
            height="300">
    </application-desc>

    <update check="background"/>
</jnlp>
```

Here is my `build.gradle` file being called like this: `./gradlew -Pversion=0.0.0 -Pdemo=true fatJar`

```
group 'com.neonorb'

apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

project.description = 'Derby Pro is pinewood derby management software.'

//create a single Jar with all dependencies
task fatJar(type: Jar) {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Version': version,
                'Main-Class': 'com.neonorb.derbypro.main.DerbyPro',
                'Demo': demo
    }
    baseName = project.name
    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
    with jar
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url "http://www.sparetimelabs.com/maven2"
    }
    mavenLocal()
}

dependencies {
    compile files('dfalex-0.9.2.jar')
    compile 'com.neonorb:commons:+'
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.5.4'
    compile group: 'commons-cli', name: 'commons-cli', version: '1.3.1'
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.4'
    compile group: 'org.controlsfx', name: 'controlsfx', version: '8.40.10'
    compile group: 'org.fxmisc.easybind', name: 'easybind', version: '1.0.3'
    compile group: 'org.scream3r', name: 'jssc', version: '2.8.0'
    compile group: 'com.sparetimelabs', name: 'purejavacomm', version: '0.0.28'
    compile 'net.java.dev.jna:jna:4.2.1'
    compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
    testCompile 'net.jodah:concurrentunit:0.4.2'
}

//Native launchers

//Windows

buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'gradle.plugin.edu.sc.seis.gradle:launch4j:1.6.1'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'edu.sc.seis.launch4j'

launch4j {
    //outputDir = 'native/windows'
    bundledJrePath = 'jre'

    dontWrapJar = true
    jar = 'bin/derby-pro.jar'

    mainClassName = 'com.neonorb.derbypro.main.DerbyPro'
    icon = '../../src/main/resources/com/neonorb/derbypro/assets/derby-pro-icon-favicon.ico'
    outfile = 'DerbyPro.exe'

    companyName = 'Neon Orb'
    productName = 'Derby Pro'
}

//OS X

/*plugins {
    id "edu.sc.seis.macAppBundle" version "2.1.0"
}

macAppBundle {
    mainClassName = "com.example.myApp.Start"
    icon = "myIcon.icns"
    bundleJRE = true
    javaProperties.put("apple.laf.useScreenMenuBar", "true")
    backgroundImage = "doc/macbackground.png"
}*/
```

Here is the manifest directory.

[image]

And here is the manifest content.

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Implementation-Version: 0.0.0
Main-Class: com.neonorb.derbypro.main.DerbyPro
Demo: true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your jar file contains duplicate entries which probably cause problems when being deployed. If you run the following command with your jar file you will see the duplicate entries:

```
$ unzip -l derby-pro-demo.jar |grep META
        0  01-26-16 11:47   META-INF/
      116  01-26-16 11:47   META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
      321  06-09-15 18:42   META-INF/LICENSE
      825  06-09-15 18:42   META-INF/NOTICE
...
    11358  06-14-15 12:06   META-INF/LICENSE.txt
      172  06-14-15 12:06   META-INF/NOTICE.txt
...
    11358  04-03-15 14:30   META-INF/LICENSE.txt
      301  04-03-15 14:30   META-INF/NOTICE.txt
```

The problem is caused by the `fatJar`. See [here](https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-1050) and [here](http://gradle.1045684.n5.nabble.com/Avoid-duplicates-when-creating-a-zip-file-td5711308.html).

When creating a fat jar, the duplicate entries should be resolved. I have no experience with gradle. The issue (first link) is still marked "open", so I assume there may not be an easy fix. As a work around (if this is possible and works for you), I could imagine to copy all jar content first to a temporary directory. This would overwrite duplicate entries. Then you could build the fat jar from the temporary directory. However, I'd be very careful with that. First some duplicate class files may be relevant, and second the LICENSE, NOTICE, etc. files certainly will cause a license problem.

Answer (score 0):

The JNLP file contains a main class attribute, Java Web Start is trying to create the manifest with that main class. Therefore removing the main class attribute from the JNLP file allows it to run.