# Hi I am trying to deploy spring mvc project in tomcat 10 but I am getting following error . I search a lot but not find the solution

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, tomcat10

I am running the project by using the startup.bat option in tomcat 10 windows.
I did not modify my code from javax to Jakarta As there are lots of codes getting changed if I modify the code also not able to find out spring dependency for Jakarta.
As per client requirement, I Have to deploy the Application on tomcat10 and java8.previously we are using tomcat9 and java8 for the application.
As per tomcat10 instructions if we deploy an application that is using javax then tomcat10 automatically converts the javax to Jakarta. I follow the process by giving the following link :
https://www.appsdeveloperblog.com/deploy-a-spring-boot-rest-app-as-a-war-to-tomcat-10/

```
26-Dec-2021 12:02:00.713 SEVERE [main] org.apache.tomcat.jakartaee.Migration.migrateArchiveStreaming Failed to migrate archive [WEB-INF/lib/sbm-java-plugin-1.3-jar-with-dependencies.jar]. Using the "-zipInMemory" option may help.
        java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: META-INF/LICENSE
                at java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream.putNextEntry(Unknown Source)
                at org.apache.tomcat.jakartaee.Migration.migrateArchiveStreaming(Migration.java:228)
                at org.apache.tomcat.jakartaee.Migration.migrateStream(Migration.java:289)
                at org.apache.tomcat.jakartaee.Migration.migrateArchiveStreaming(Migration.java:229)
                at org.apache.tomcat.jakartaee.Migration.migrateStream(Migration.java:289)
                at org.apache.tomcat.jakartaee.Migration.migrateFile(Migration.java:200)
                at org.apache.tomcat.jakartaee.Migration.execute(Migration.java:166)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.migrateLegacyApp(HostConfig.java:1298)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$MigrateApp.run(HostConfig.java:2048)
                at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
                at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.migrateLegacyApps(HostConfig.java:1260)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:471)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1708)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:320)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:366)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:946)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:886)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)
                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
                at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:263)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:432)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:927)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:795)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:345)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:476)
26-Dec-2021 12:02:00.804 SEVERE [main] org.apache.tomcat.jakartaee.Migration.migrateArchiveStreaming Failed to migrate archive [URWAYPGService.war]. Using the "-zipInMemory" option may help.
        java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: META-INF/LICENSE
                at java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream.putNextEntry(Unknown Source)
                at org.apache.tomcat.jakartaee.Migration.migrateArchiveStreaming(Migration.java:228)
                at org.apache.tomcat.jakartaee.Migration.migrateStream(Migration.java:289)
                at org.apache.tomcat.jakartaee.Migration.migrateArchiveStreaming(Migration.java:229)
                at org.apache.tomcat.jakartaee.Migration.migrateStream(Migration.java:289)
                at org.apache.tomcat.jakartaee.Migration.migrateFile(Migration.java:200)
                at org.apache.tomcat.jakartaee.Migration.execute(Migration.java:166)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.migrateLegacyApp(HostConfig.java:1298)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$MigrateApp.run(HostConfig.java:2048)
                at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
                at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.migrateLegacyApps(HostConfig.java:1260)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:471)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1708)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:320)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:366)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:946)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:886)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)
                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
                at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:263)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:432)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:927)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:795)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:345)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:476)
26-Dec-2021 12:02:00.807 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.migrateLegacyApp Migration failure
        java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: META-INF/LICENSE
                at java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream.putNextEntry(Unknown Source)
                at org.apache.tomcat.jakartaee.Migration.migrateArchiveStreaming(Migration.java:228)
                at org.apache.tomcat.jakartaee.Migration.migrateStream(Migration.java:289)
                at org.apache.tomcat.jakartaee.Migration.migrateArchiveStreaming(Migration.java:229)
                at org.apache.tomcat.jakartaee.Migration.migrateStream(Migration.java:289)
                at org.apache.tomcat.jakartaee.Migration.migrateFile(Migration.java:200)
                at org.apache.tomcat.jakartaee.Migration.execute(Migration.java:166)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.migrateLegacyApp(HostConfig.java:1298)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$MigrateApp.run(HostConfig.java:2048)
                at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
                at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.migrateLegacyApps(HostConfig.java:1260)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:471)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1708)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:320)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:366)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:946)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:886)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)
                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
                at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:263)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:432)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:927)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:795)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:345)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:476)
26-Dec-2021 12:02:00.825 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [D:\SAUDI_PG\upgrade-tomcat-10\apache-tomcat-10.0.14-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-10.0.14\webapps\docs]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your jar file contains duplicate entries which probably cause problems when being deployed. If you run the following command with your jar file you will see the duplicate entries:

```
    $ unzip -l URWAYPGService.war |grep META
```

Comment: Hi i tried this command but i dont see duplicate enetries Please see the below output for this command      
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root   61925617 Dec 21 17:52 URWAYPGService.war
root@css-urway-uat:/opt/tomcat-10/webapps# unzip -l URWAYPGService.war |grep META
        0  2021-12-21 16:18   META-INF/
      104  2021-12-21 16:18   META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
root@css-urway-uat:/opt/tomcat-10/webapps# ls -l

Comment: please check this question  : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35020003/java-util-zip-zipexception-duplicate-entry-meta-inf-license-txt

Comment: I also suggest you to do this : Downgrade the tomcat version and it will be okay .

Comment: Check out https://p.4ce.ca/DDDn (short url to a minecraft forum with similar and same issue)

Comment: issue is solved by unzip jar file delete duplicate entry from that jar file